# Does updating PHP affect older Joomla versions?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a server with many sites in different joomla versions, I need with the new joomla 3.0 update the php. I currently use the php 5.2.4 and joomla 3 requires 5.3.x minimum

My question is update the php affect the others sites?, in the server are pages from joomla 1.5, 1.6 , 1.7 and 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have no problems with your joomla 1.6+ sites, since that version was made for php5. Besides, they're all upgradable to 2.5. I'm not so sure about your joomla 1.5 sites, though. If you're running the latest joomla version that came out, you should be mostly fine, but you could face some problems, specially with extensions because 1.5 only required php4. What I would suggest is that you install a new php instance and control through htaccess what instance every site runs.

Cheers.

Comment: Joomla 1.5 really imo is a pain on php 5.3, it has tons of E_STRICT errors for example. There are certainly people with a business model of supporting 1. in modern environments but it's not simple.

Comment: @Elin: I've been able to run it in php5, but like you say it can become a headache very quickly, specially if there are many extensions and/or customizations, that's why I proposed running both php4 and php5 and not just upgrading php4 to 5.